# Pig Latin Program removes puncuation mark for some reason. Any clue on why?

Tags: python

We are doing a lab where we do Pig Latin. The word changes, but it is supposed to keep the exclamation mark at the end. For some reason, the word changes into Pig Latin, but the exclamation mark is gone at the end of the word.

```
def convertWord(word):
    lastChar = (word[len(word) - 1:-2:-1])
    convertedWord = ""
    listVowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
    listPunctuation = ["!",".",",","?"]
    havePunct = False
    #think becomes inkthay
    #access each letter at a time in word
    if lastChar in listPunctuation:
        havePunct = True
        word = word[0:len(word)-1]
    if word[0:1].lower() in listVowels:
        convertedWord = word + "way "
    for letter in word:
        if letter.lower() in listVowels:
            posVowel = word.index(letter)
            #extract all letters up to posVowel
            beginWord = word[0:posVowel]
            convertedWord = word[posVowel:] + beginWord + "ay "
            break
    if havePunct == True:
        convertedWord = convertedWord + " "
    if word[0:1].isupper():
        convertedWord = convertedWord.capitalize()
    return convertedWord
def main():
      print(convertWord("Science!"))
main()
```

I'm still sort of new to Python, so does anyone know why? The word Science is supposed to return Iencescay! It returns the word Iencescay, but it removes the exclamation mark on the end.

Comment: You remove the ending punctuation in `if lastChar in listPunctuation`.

Comment: You aren't storing what punctuation is at the end of the argument word, just removing it. `word = word[0:len(word)-1]`. Currently you are just adding a single whitespace to the end of the converted word `convertedWord = convertedWord + " "`, not a punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

1. In `if lastChar in listPunctuation:` you remove the "!".
2. Why don't you use `lastChar = word[-1]`?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).